# Which is the proper way to set and use MenuInfo Structure?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winapi, structure

I'm a bit confussed, the menuinfo structure in MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647575%28v=vs.85%29.aspx says:

```
hbrBack
Type: HBRUSH
A handle to the brush to be used for the menu's background.
```

So... How I could get that necessary brush handle?, I can't see any handle method for a Brush object... is a Brush, this is confussing.

And also, I can't just use a bitmap for the menu background?, I've tried to use a bitmap handle but the menu background does not changed.

> UPDATE

This code does not worked, does not changed the background color.

```
Public Sub SetMenuBackground()

    MenuHandle = GetSystemMenu(form.Handle, False)

    Dim brush As IntPtr =
        CreateSolidBrush(CUInt(ColorTranslator.ToWin32(Color.Red)))

    Dim mi As New MenuInfo
    mi.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(MenuInfo))
    mi.fMask = &H2 ' MIM_BACKGROUND
    mi.hbrBack = brush

    SetMenuInfo(MenuHandle, mi)

End Sub
```

The API func and the structure:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function SetMenuInfo(
        ByVal hmenu As IntPtr,
        <[In]> ByRef lpcmi As MenuInfo
) As Boolean
End Function

Private Structure MenuInfo
    Dim cbSize As Int32
    Dim fMask As Int32
    Dim dwStyle As Int32
    Dim cyMax As Int32
    Dim hbrBack As IntPtr
    Dim dwContextHelpID As Int32
    Dim dwMenuData As Int32
    Public Sub New(ByVal owner As Control)
        cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(MENUINFO))
    End Sub
End Structure
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183518(v=vs.85).aspx (its not an object, its a handle to a brush)

Comment: You using a WinApi function, you need to use a Brush reference created the same way. http://pinvoke.net/search.aspx?search=brush&namespace=[All]

Comment: You're trying to mix several different types of handles (`HBITMAP` != `HBRUSH`, for instance, and `Graphics.Bitmap` != `BITMAP`). It might help clarify things if you explain *why* you want to use a WinAPI `MENUINFO` structure (designed for raw API calls) in .NET code. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @Ken White The reason is I'm trying to manage the system menu using APIS then I need to know how to use the menuinfo to change the style, the background, and the other things, thanks

Comment: Please guys see my update, the brush don't worked for me, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `mi.hbrBack = COLOR_ACTIVECAPTION + 1` for instance. Does this work? Your updated example should work api wise..

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz sorry but I don't know what I need to replace for "COLOR_ACTIVECAPTION" (GetSysColor api maybe?), my code above does not work.

Comment: It is '2'. Just assign 3.  Try setting mi.cbSize first, to the size of a MenuInfo structure.

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz the cbsize member is set automatycally in the API NEW constructor, anyways I will try it. EDIT: No way, does not chanegd anything

Comment: @Elektro - No need to try then, I didn't know that.

Comment: @Elektro - Don't know how you call it, but I just tested - you have to pass 'false' as 'bRevert' parameter to `GetSystemMenu` for the brush to have an effect.

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz yes thankyou I know, I'm always passing False as brevert parametter, sorry for not giving the full code but are more than 1.000 lines of miscellaneous systemmenu methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed the structure and now it works fine

```
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.
StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential,
CharSet:=System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)>
Public Structure MenuInfo
    Public cbSize As UInteger
    Public fMask As UInteger
    Public dwStyle As UInteger
    Public cyMax As UInteger
    Public hbrBack As IntPtr
    Public dwContextHelpID As UInteger
    Public dwMenuData As UIntPtr
End Structure
```

What I've learned with this?: pinvoke.net site does not ever provide efficient/working examples.